# String compression : Turn AAAbbCCCC into 3Abb4C

Tags: php, string, compression

i'm facing a logic problem. let's say I have a given string "AAAbbCCCC". I want to compress it into something like "3Abb4C".
So when a character is repeated at least 3 (2 isn't necessary, as it wouldn't compress the sequence) times in a row, I should replace this sequence into the number of repetitions followed by the character.

I really dont find how to write this script smartly. of course, the script should work for every string possible. The string can only contains letters, lower or uppercase ("A" and "a" are not considered as the same occurence)

Comment: This sounds like homework to me, and particularly *bad* homework at that: the stereotypical, not applicable to any real world problem, ever, programming assignment. At any length, it's not appropriate for StackOverflow.

Comment: This is exactly what compression [eg gz] does, except way less efficient. Why not simply use `gzcompress($string)`?

Comment: Use preg_replace_callback with strlen().

Comment: Demo: https://eval.in/155820

Comment: What does your try look like?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$string = 'AAAbbCCCCcccgGGG';

$compressed = preg_replace_callback( '/(\pL)\1{2,}/', function( $matches ) {
    return strlen( $matches[0] ) . $matches[1];
}, $string );

echo $compressed;    // 3Abb4C3cg3G 

/*
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \p{L}                    any character of: UTF macro 'L' ( Letter )
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \1{2,}                   what was matched by capture \1 (at least 2
                           times (matching the most amount possible))                          
*/
```